# How to Filter a 2-dimensional List?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter the following list:

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>()
{
  new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5},
  new List<int>(){6,7,5,4,5},
  new List<int>(){1,3,3,222,1}
}
```

**My filter condition should be: "include only odd numbers"**, so my list shouldn't have any even numbers after the filter is applied.

My Attempt:

```
list = list.Where(x => x.Where(y => y%2 == 1).ToList()).ToList()
```

**Desired Output:**

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>()
{
  new List<int>(){1,3,5},
  new List<int>(){7,5,5},
  new List<int>(){1,3,3,1}
}
```

I know how to use Linq on single-dimensional collections, but not sure how to make this one work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
list = list.Select(x => x.Where(i => i % 2 == 1).ToList())
           .Where(x => x.Any())
           .ToList();
```

Here, we're using `Select()` to iterate the elements of the *outer* list, then using `Where()` to filter the *inner* list. After that, we call `Where()` on the *outer* list to filter out empty inner lists. That last part is optional; feel free to remove it if you need to keep empty lists.

**Note:** As [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) stated in the comments, it's probably better to use `i % 2 != 0` *if you want to keep negative odd numbers*.

Comment: `i => i % 2 != 0` is more accurate, since *negative* odd numbers have negative remainder: `-3 % 2 == -1`  (note, `-1`, not `1`) in c#.